# Does each retrieval of an HttpContext.Current.Session object stored OutOfProc make a call to the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Our MVC web app is load balanced and makes use of the session to persist data out of proc in SQL server. Web config is set up like so:

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" sqlConnectionString="Data Source..."/>
```

Using dependency injection we pass a class wrapping our session to the various controllers

```
public class MyWebSession : IWebSession
{
    private const MyModelKey = "MyModelKey"
    public MyModel MyModel
    {
        get { return (MyModel ) HttpContext.Current.Session[MyModelKey]; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session[MyModelKey] = value; }
    }
}
```

My question is if in our controllers we do things like this:

```
var id = MyWebSession.MyModel.Id;
var description = MyModel.Id.Description;
```

Would that incur multiple trips to the database? Or has that hit already occurred when the http request is made and I can treat the session data as in-memory variables?

Answer (score 0):

[Current](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.web/HttpContext.cs,917b79cec44466cd) refers to [ContextBase](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.web/Hosting/ContextBase.cs,f4e667f78d6f021d), which refers to [HostContext](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/remoting/callcontext.cs,a50bbd25fbb95ba5), which looks like this:

```
    public static Object HostContext
    {
        [System.Security.SecurityCritical]  // auto-generated
        get
        {
            ExecutionContext.Reader ec = Thread.CurrentThread.GetExecutionContextReader();

            Object hC = ec.IllogicalCallContext.HostContext;
            if (hC == null)
                hC = ec.LogicalCallContext.HostContext;
            return hC;
        }
```

`IllogicalCallContext` [looks like this](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs,4afee5a4aa8a9438):

```
internal class IllogicalCallContext
{
    private Hashtable m_Datastore;
    private Object m_HostContext;

    internal struct Reader
    {
        IllogicalCallContext m_ctx;

        public Reader(IllogicalCallContext ctx) { m_ctx = ctx; }

        public bool IsNull { get { return m_ctx == null; } }

        [System.Security.SecurityCritical]
        public Object GetData(String name) { return IsNull ? null : m_ctx.GetData(name); }

        public Object HostContext { get { return IsNull ? null : m_ctx.HostContext; } }
    }

    private Hashtable Datastore
    {
        get 
        { 
            if (null == m_Datastore)
            {
                // The local store has not yet been created for this thread.
                m_Datastore = new Hashtable();
            }
            return m_Datastore;
        }
    }

    internal Object HostContext
    {
        get
        {
            return m_HostContext;
        }
        set
        {
            m_HostContext = value;
        }
    }

        public Object HostContext { get { return IsNull ? null : m_ctx.HostContext; } }
    }
```

..etc.

Eventually you wind up in `CallContext.HostContext`, [which looks like this](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/remoting/callcontext.cs,a8b611362498cfd9):

```
    internal Object HostContext
    {
        get
        {
            return m_HostContext;
        }
        set
        {
            m_HostContext = value;
        }
    }
```

So whatever behavior occurs is going to depend on what someone puts in that `HostContext` property. This is where the Reference Source ends, so presumably someone or something is putting a dictionary or caching object in there, though I suppose it could be a database endpoint.

By the way, somewhere in this labyrinth should be a `SessionState` object that looks like this:

https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/State/SessionState.cs